# Clickable email-links encryption? How to do them?

Tags: email, encryption, web, spam-prevention

I would like to know if and how it is possible to create a clickable email-link for websites, that are "encrypted" in a way emailspiders can't collect them and it is still possible for living users to click it to open in email-clients or even copy it.

I saw some links that were done in javascript but I on't know how they did this and how "safe" they are.

thank you in advance for any reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most approaches to this are splitting the address across multiple elements and inserting extra formatting; then for JS-enabled browsers, they use JavaScript to turn it back into an e-mail address.

The poster example for this is [SpamSpan](http://www.spamspan.com/), which even has several "levels" of obfuscation - each level progressively less and less resembles an e-mail in the source code, yet it still manages to piece it back together by JS. Although some spambots today are supposedly capable of executing JavaScript, te vast majority doesn't - and the e-mails are still human-readable with JS off. An advantage of JS-assisted de/obfuscation is that it doesn't rely on external servers, you just need to (simply) integrate the JS library.

Another approach is taken by [reCAPTCHA Mailhide](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/) - the e-mail is revealed only after solving a CAPTCHA (same type as for normal reCAPTCHA). This is less convenient for the user, but practically safe against robots. A disadvantage of this is that it depends on reCAPTCHA's servers (in essence, on Google) - some people are dead-set against any external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a very simple and effective way:

[Scramble email addresses](http://www.golivecentral.com/pages/txttut/scramble.shtml)

All it does is convert it into ASCII, and all you need to do is insert it where your email address would go!

Although there are more (crazily) secure ways you can choose, this would be the simply option. You can also try [this solution](http://joemaller.com/js-mailer.shtml), it uses JavaScript to protect your email.

Hope this helps!